# In my application trying to get notification whenver db in webserver updates. How this can be achieved?

Tags: java, android

Im using Jersey Rest service for my local web server. This is used for user login and registering from android. I also trying to achieve when ever a new user is added the admin should get a notification. How this can be achieved? I recently came to know about Jersey Sse. Is it achievable through Jersey SSe. Please help me find a easy sample/document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a new user is registered, which means a new ID is made in the DB of the User. Run a `Android Service` for Admin, which will call a Server Script to check if new ID is available or not. If new ID found for the User deploy a notification to Admin.

> Dummy Code [Change as per yours]

```
public class your_service extends Service {


public your_service() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, your_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
       // add code, ur logic
       //notify here
       //                         
     }
    }, 
       new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
             {//empty
             }
          });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext()).add(request);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 60000); //repeat this code every 1 minutes
             }
          }, 1000); // first wait for 1 seconds
        }
       }
    };
    return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

Comment: Found out another way by using FireBase messaging.

Comment: Consider accepting if helped and share the link FireBase messaging to me also

Comment: I am new to stack overflow how to accept your answer?

Comment: I studied using this link. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-android/. Lets try it out. Also as per my understanding the sample above will always ping with server every time. Right?

Comment: @JibinNajeeb yes every 1 minute, it will ping server

Comment: By using Firebase notification, the server ping can be reduced to a single time